# Why do I see this error in android web-view in vue.js

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js

I am using vue.js in my web app and everything works fine in desktop browsers but not in mobile, so I installed android emulator to see what's the problem and I was surprised to see this (I used remote debugging in chrome) : 
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL     vueapp.js:4

[image]

why do I see this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't support template strings yet:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals